# C json encoding with mjson library

Tags: c, json

I'm working with mjson library ( http://mjson.sourceforge.net/ ) to do some simple json encoding. The json output should be something like

```
{ "type" : "mytype" , "hostname" : "myhostname" ... "state" : "mystate" }
```

My function return `{}`, or based on this example : http://mjson.sourceforge.net/examples.html
i make the function return `state : "state : "myState" { "type" : "mytype" ....` , state being outside of the array.

Here my encoding function :

```
json_t *make_LogEntryToJson( NAGIOS_LOGENTRY *logEntry )
{

    json_t *entry, *label, *value ;

    // create an entry node
    entry = json_new_object();

    // insert the first label-value pair
    label = json_new_string("type");
    value = json_new_string( logEntry -> type );
    json_insert_child( label, value);
    json_insert_child(entry, label );

    // insert the second label-value pair
    label = json_new_string("hostname");
    value = json_new_string( logEntry -> hostname );
    json_insert_child( label, value);
    json_insert_child(entry, label );

    // insert the second label-value pair
    label = json_new_string("srvname");
    value = json_new_string(logEntry -> srvname);
    json_insert_child( label, value);
    json_insert_child(entry, label );

    // insert the second label-value pair
    label = json_new_string("libelle");
    value = json_new_string( logEntry -> libelle );
    json_insert_child( label, value);
    json_insert_child(entry, label );

    // insert the second label-value pair
    label = json_new_string("timestamp");
    value = json_new_string( logEntry -> timestamp );
    json_insert_child( label, value);
    json_insert_child(entry, label );

    // insert the second label-value pair
    label = json_new_string("stateType");
    value = json_new_string( logEntry -> stateType );
    json_insert_child( label, value);
    json_insert_child(entry, label );

    // insert the second label-value pair
    label = json_new_string("state");
    value = json_new_string( logEntry -> state );
    json_insert_child( label, value);
    json_insert_child(entry, label );

    return entry ;
}
```

Any Help would be greatly appreciated !